# How to connect to JMX for JVM on local machine by pid (Java 9+)

Tags: java, jmx

I want to query an MBean on a JVM running on the local machine.

```
String address = "???";
JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL(address))
  .getMBeanServerConnection()
  .getAttribute(new ObjectName("<object name>"), "<attribute name>");
```

I have not set up com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=XXX, but since the jconsole GUI is still able to connect to a JVM and observe/interact with the MBeans there (I've tested this), I assume it's possible to craft an address string that references a JVM process running on a particular pid (since no jmxremote.port=XXX will exist).

However, I can find no documentation on how to construct an address for a local JVM process with a specified pid.

There are some answers from 5+ years ago that use the sun.management.ConnectorAddressLink class, but this class has been removed in Java 9+. I've also tried looking through the source code of several projects such as [jmxlocal](https://github.com/nickman/jmxlocal), but all of these projects are now out of date, and also use that same [ConnectorAddressLink class](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/management/ConnectorAddressLink.java#L112) which is now unavailable.

Comment: Refer : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html

Comment: A sample is already provided Refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html.

Answer (score 2):

full sample source code: https://github.com/banv-dev/DemoDumpHeap/blob/master/src/main/java/org/example/Main.java

```
//attach to VM with pid
VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach("pid");
//Starts the local JMX management agent in the target virtual machine.
String jmxUrl = vm.startLocalManagementAgent()

//connect via JMX
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(jmxUrl);
JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
MBeanServerConnection beanServerConnection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
```

reference: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.attach/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/management/monitoring-and-management-using-jmx-technology.html#GUID-805517EC-2D33-4D61-81D8-4D0FA770D1B8

Answer (score 0):

(I presume you are not inquiring about the format of the string, just about how to find the port.)

You could agree on some contract for jmx port(s). If you were to have 2+ jvms on the localhost, they obviously would have distinct ports so the jmx client can't just guess nor port scan (bad etiquette). Maybe a port range to blindly try to connect to.

You could rely on something else, like a broadcast packet, or multicast channel convention to request your programs to reveal they exist on some jmx port, but that you would have to program yourself and expect the jvms to start such module.

Otherwise, on linux by browsing /proc/... you might discover processes (filtering only java ones) and which port they have opened, or some runtime exec backflips with netstat (linux or windows) you might be able to list listening sockets. But again, that doesn't mean these sockets are JMX service - you still need a convention unless you want to probe and hassle the processes arbitrary ports.

However, if you can list processes, you probably can obtain their command lines and find java ones, and their own jmx system properties revealing the port they use...

Few things to try. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your ideas. Just in case it isn't clear, I'm not talking about a situation where I have com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=XXX set but did not keep track of what XXX was for that JVM. I'm talking about when jmxremote is *not* set, and so no port has been assigned to listen. In this circumstance, I can still easily use jconsole to connect to that JVM and query all the MBeans there (I've tested this). So unless there is some kind of hidden TCP listening port that is assigned anyway which jconsole is using, locating a listening port doesn't sound like what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Ok then. I would hope it's a port. I guess my next step would be to check the listening ports of such jvm, or even the established connections once you have jconsole hooked. But if it is really a localhost thing, then it may well be a name pipe or even shared memory (non pure-java). After all, it's a hotspot-specific thing right? They can afford making native code for that. You may have to find openjdk code and hope to find the code they use (if you are allowed to use it).